# Repeated variables in ggplot2

Tags: ggplot2

A minimum working example code:

```
df <- data.frame()
df[1:2,"year"] <- 2012L
df[3:7, "year"] <- 2013L
df[8:16, "year"] <- 2014L
df$team <- c("Team_A", "Team_B", "Team_A", "Team_B", "Team_C",
         "Team_D", "Team_E", "Team_A", "Team_B", "Team_C",
         "Team_D", "Team_E", "Team_F", "Team_G", "Team_H",
         "Team_I")
df$matches <- c(4, 2, 9, 7, 3, 4, 1, 16, 13, 10, 8, 9, 2,3,1, 3)
df
```

The dataframe looks like this:

```
    year     team  matches
1   2012    Team_A  4
2   2012    Team_B  2
3   2013    Team_A  9
4   2013    Team_B  7
5   2013    Team_C  3
6   2013    Team_D  4
7   2013    Team_E  1
8   2014    Team_A  16
9   2014    Team_B  13
10  2014    Team_C  10
11  2014    Team_D  8
12  2014    Team_E  9
13  2014    Team_F  2
14  2014    Team_G  3
15  2014    Team_H  1
16  2014    Team_I  3
```

The matches are plot yearwise:

```
match_plot_yearwise <- ggplot(df, aes(matches, team, color = year)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x = matches, y = team, xend = matches, yend = team), 
                   color= "grey50") +
  geom_point() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
  ) 
match_plot_yearwise
```

This gives the following plot:
[image]

If a team plays more than one year then, how to repeat the team name on y-axis that many times, instead of stacking it's each year match one above the other?

Comment: Thanks for your question. Unfortunately it is difficult to determine what you need from this information alone. Can you please provide an example of code that you have tried so far, and explain more clearly why it doesn't give the desired result?

Comment: Provided an example of code

Comment: maybe you would like to consider creating subplots to make different plots for each year. Also try to keep year on x- axis, or make year a factor instead of continuous variable.

Comment: Thanks for your response.. However, I'm afraid, I don't want to use subplots..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution pastes `team` and `year` together in a single variable, but labels the y-axis with the team name only. I could not tell what you wanted to do with the `geom_segment()` so I omitted it. (In your example plots it creates segments with length 0.) I had to sort `df` so that the labels would appear in the correct places.

### data

```
df <- read.table(textConnection('    year     team  matches
1   2012    Team_A  4
2   2012    Team_B  2
3   2013    Team_A  9
4   2013    Team_B  7
5   2013    Team_C  3
6   2013    Team_D  4
7   2013    Team_E  1
8   2014    Team_A  16
9   2014    Team_B  13
10  2014    Team_C  10
11  2014    Team_D  8
12  2014    Team_E  9
13  2014    Team_F  2
14  2014    Team_G  3
15  2014    Team_H  1
16  2014    Team_I  3'))
```

### code

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

df <- df %>% 
  arrange(team, year)

ggplot(df, aes(x = matches, y = interaction(year, team), color = factor(year))) +

  geom_point() +
  scale_y_discrete(labels = df$team) +
  theme_minimal() +

  theme(
    panel.grid = element_blank(),
  )
```

### output

[image]

Comment: That helps! Thank you!!